# PostgreSQL index in multi-column WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-update

I'm trying to optimize queries modelled on the following example:

```
UPDATE posts
SET title = "Example", lock_version = 1
WHERE (
    posts.id = 123
    AND
    posts.lock_version = 0
)
```

I have a unique index on `posts.id`, which ensures that positive hits on `WHERE posts.id = 123` will never return more than one result.

**Do I also need an index on `posts.lock_version`?**

I imagine I would need it if the first part of the `WHERE` returned more than one result, because the index would make it faster to narrow down the filter.

What about the situation I described, though?

Comment: If posts.id is a primary key (or otherwise unique: a candidate key) then alll other columns are functionally dependant on it , and an extra index would not be needed, given that you always use the PK to address a row,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** If `posts.id` is unique, you don't need more than the simple index on that column.

It won't get any faster - on the contrary: since you update the row, you would add maintenance cost to update the additional index as well.

Aside: you don't need the parentheses in your `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE id = 123
AND   lock_version = 0
```

And if you double-quote `"Example"` it refers to a column of that name. You probably want the value: `'Example'`. Single quotes for a string literal.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're also right about the format.